# Get next key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$array = [
    "sdf" => 500,
    "gsda" => 1000,
    "bsdf" => 1500,
    "bads" => 2000,
    "iurt" => 2500,
    "poli" => 3000
];
```

How can I get the name of the next key? For example if the current array is `gsda`, I need `bsdf`.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: For anyone who can't figure out how to adjust the answers below to access the next value ...of course you use the returned key on the input array.

Comment: @Jordy The unsuitable accepted answer cannot be deleted by its author while it has the green tick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: Note that this is *not* a valid answer, as it's searching for values instead of keys.

---

If the pointer of `current()` is on the right key, @Thomas_Cantonnet is right and you want to use `next()`. If you did not iterate through the array via next(), you first have to go through the array to set the internal index pointer correctly:

```
$search = "bsdf";
while (($next = next($array)) !== NULL) {
    if ($next == $search) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Now $next points to your current search-index and you can iterate over the rest via `next()`.

Comment: next() returns false if there are no more elements

Comment: @trocolo Completely right - and the OP asked for keys and not values. I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 34):

If pointer is not on this element, as other solutions assume, You can use

```
<?php
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    print $keys[array_search("gsda",$keys)+1];
```

Comment: It will cause an issue for the last element. Should be `$keys = array_keys($arr); $index = array_search("gsda",$keys); if ( count($arr) <= $index+1 ) { print 'end of array'; } else { print $keys[$index+1]; }` to correctly handle array boundaries.

Comment: to check if is last one or not, add `isset`

Answer (score 20):

```
$next = next($array); 
echo key($array);
```

Should return the key corresponding to $next;

Answer (score 1):

```php
// move to the next position
next($array);
// get the key
$key = key($array);
// return to the original position
prev($array);
```